# Do cars have a specific brake and power steering fluid or are they universal?

Tags: service, brake-fluid, power-steering-fluid

I am servicing my standard hyundai coupe 2006.  Things like the engine oil, air filter and coolant have to be the specific ones for your car.

However what about power steering and brake fluid, I can't find anything about specific power steering or brake fluids for the car. Is it universal?  If I just top up mixing with whatevers already in there will that be a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Vehicle manufacturers have a specification for all of their fluids and it should be in the owners manual.  Many vehicles do share similar specifications for power steering and brake fluid,  but it is a terrible idea to assume anything is universal.

Most part stores have the specs in their catalogs, but if there is doubt, the dealer will have the correct fluid.

Comment: Brake fluid is *fairly* universal. Most vehicles will use DOT3/4. Power steering fluid can be quite different between makes. Thinking in particular about Honda/Acura using a very specific type. A lot of vehicles will use Dexron transmission fluid for the power steering. You are spot on in saying you need to look at the Owner's Manual or check with the dealer to make sure!

Comment: On some Chrysler electric steering systems they use a hydraulic pump that takes mineral oil...

Comment: It is very challenging: dot 5.1 can be mixed with dot 4 BUT don’t mix dot 5 with anything else., as dot 5 is silicone based unlike dot 4 and 5.1 which are glycol based...